# How to select distinct pairs in MySQL join (same table) with transitivity?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing a very poorly designed database with a non-normalized table X.
This table X should have a N:M relationship with another table Y.

The problem is that this relationship is currently 1:N and the jerry-rigged solution until now was to duplicate the entries when there was various registries to be related.

Simplifying, I have this:

```
| ID | TEXT | LOCATION_ID |
| 1  | foo  |      1      |
| 2  | foo  |      2      |
| 3  | bar  |      1      |
| 4  | bar  |      4      |
| 5  | bar  |      3      |
```

I have to normalize this table. So, my first idea was try to obtain pairs of similar registries. Something like this:

```
| a.ID | b.ID | 
|   1  |  2   |
|   3  |  4   |
|   3  |  5   |
```

Experimenting a little bit:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM mytable AS a 
INNER JOIN mytable AS b 
   ON a.text = b.text AND a.id != b.id 
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
```

This lead to a problem like this:

```
| a.ID | b.ID | 
|   1  |  2   |
|   2  |  1   |
|   3  |  4   |
|   3  |  5   |
|   4  |  3   |
|   4  |  5   |
|   5  |  3   |
|   5  |  4   |
```

The pairs were duplicated.

After some digging, I realized that this was more efficient:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM mytable AS a 
INNER JOIN mytable AS b 
        ON a.text = b.text AND a.id < b.id 
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
```

So, I got this:

```
| a.ID | b.ID | 
|   1  |  2   |
|   3  |  4   |
|   3  |  5   |
|   4  |  5   |
```

But I still need to get rid of that last register.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Group on only one side and take the [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) of the other:

```
SELECT   MIN(a.ID) a, b.ID b
FROM     mytable a JOIN mytable b ON b.text = a.text AND b.ID > a.ID
GROUP BY b.ID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4eab8/1/0).