# Matching fighters from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with fighter records and I need to match them accordingly by level, weight, sex and type of fight sport. This is the structure of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `tfc_sparring_requests_athletes` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullname` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `fightsport` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `teamid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I tried to make a query like this in order to match the fighters

```
select a.fullname,b.fullname,a.weight
    from tfc_sparring_requests_athletes a ,
             tfc_sparring_requests_athletes b 
where a.weight = b.weight
    and a.fightsport = b.fightsport 
    and a.level =b.level 
    and a.sex = b.sex 
    and a.fullname != b.fullname
```

and the result is

```
fighter23   fighter1    78
fighter6    fighter5    70
fighter5    fighter6    70
fighter1    fighter23   78
fighter26   fighter25   57
fighter25   fighter26   57
fighter28   fighter27   80
fighter27   fighter28   80
```

As you can see fighter 1 is matched with fighter 23 in row 1 but in row 4 fighters appear again. Also other fighters repeat their match as well like fighter 5 and 6 in row 2 and 3. How can I avoid this repetition so I can show the matches uniquely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway I found the solution based on this question [How to select distinct pairs in MySQL join (same table) with transitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632400/how-to-select-distinct-pairs-in-mysql-join-same-table-with-transitivity)

```
select MIN(a.id),b.id,a.fullname name1,b.fullname name2,a.weight
    from tfc_sparring_requests_athletes a ,tfc_sparring_requests_athletes b 
where a.weight = b.weight
    and a.fightsport = b.fightsport 
    and a.level =b.level 
    and a.sex = b.sex 
    and a.fullname != b.fullname
    AND b.id > a.id
GROUP BY b.id;
```